# Dart assert not working when use List.length

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check List length when initialize class.
I tried but it did not work as expected.
My code is here.

```dart
@immutable
class TestClass {
  const TestClass(this.values)
      : assert(values.length >= 0 && values.length <= 4);

  final List<int> values;
}

const a = TestClass(<int>[1, 1, 1]); // assert
```

[image]

How can I get it to behave as expected?

#### Edit 1

Now the assertion no longer works.
[image]

#### Edit 2

[image]

#### Edit 3

```dart
// OK
final ok = TestClass(const <int>[1]);

// NG
final ng = TestClass(const <int>[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]);
```

#### Edit 4

```dart
@immutable
class TestClass2 {
  const TestClass2(
      this.value,
      ) : assert(value.length == 3);

  final String value;
}

final a = TestClass2('abcde');
```

I think `T.length` doesn't work in assert.

#### Edit 5

[image]

#### Edit 6

[image]

Comment: What will be your assert condition ?

Comment: I want to show an assertion if the length of the list is not less than 0 and not greater than 4.

Comment: Ok change this => assert(values.length <= 4);

Comment: I tried but didn't work.

Comment: How you using this class, I mean the test case

Comment: I added `Edit 4`. I think `length` property doesn't work in assert.

Comment: I;ve used as test, it shows the error

Comment: I added `Edit 5`. Why does this example throw an exception in the static analysis?

Comment: I think it's a bug.  I recommend [filing an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues).  In general you can't call functions in a `const` constructor since they generally cannot be evaluated at compile-time.  That includes accessing properties since that's equivalent to invoking a getter.  There are some exceptions when dealing with literals; possibly `List.length` is intended to be one of them since it doesn't seem to generate an "Invalid constant expression" error.

Comment: @yukitaka13 My test was using `final a = ....`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added `Edit 6`. `String.length` worked as expected.

Comment: Can you explain why String.length is evaluated at compile time and List.length is not?

Comment: @yukitaka13 As I said, it's probably a bug.  File an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, so I'll add it as an answer.

Apparently, this is working as expected. Found [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37503) on the Dart SDK repository which is similar. In a comment someone [referenced](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37503#issuecomment-510570623) the following from the language specification:

> You cannot get the length of a list in a constant expression. The language specification says so [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/06986298f21bd8cfce145448177e654dc9c26598/specification/dartLangSpec.tex#L6176):
>
> ```
> \item An expression of the form \code{$e$.length} is potentially constant
>   if $e$ is a potentially constant expression.
>   It is further constant if $e$ is a constant expression that
>   evaluates to an instance of \code{String}.
> ```
>
> So it must be rejected at compile-time. This is one of many situations where it's tempting to make Dart constant expressions just a little bit more expressive, but it is quite costly (in so many ways) so it's not very likely to happen. One issue is that you can write a `class MyList extends List<String> {...}` and make the `length` getter run arbitrary code, and still have a `const` constructor in `MyList`, and constant expressions will not run arbitrary code, so you'd need to find the right borderline between the lists where `.length` is OK and the lists where it isn't, and the type system wouldn't be able to prevent the latter from occurring where a `List` or `List<T>` for some `T` is specified.

Not sure if there's a way around this, but I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
@immutable
class TestClass {
  const TestClass(this.values) : assert(values.length == 0 || values.length > 4);

  final List<int> values;
}
```

I edited my answer you will get a warning if values ​​variable has no elements or has more than 4 elements

Comment: Now the assertion no longer works. I added picture.

Comment: You are incorrectly understanding the specifications of the asserts. An exception is thrown if the conditional expression passed to the assert is false. I added a picture to Edit2.

Comment: I tried but didn't work.

Comment: I added examples. See edit3.